# trying to understand this C++ syntax

Tags: c++

What does this mean? I'm aware that this should be the constructor for an instance in the Deck class, but I don't understand the syntax  `myCards(DECKSIZE), debugging(debug)` after `Deck(bool debug)`?

```
Deck::Deck (bool debug): myCards(DECKSIZE), debugging(debug) {
    for (int k=0; k<DECKSIZE; k++) {
        myCards[k].ChangeCard(k);
    }
    Shuffle ();
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: That's where the constructor calls for all of the data members go.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor?

Answer (score 1):

It initializes member object `myCards` with `DECKSIZE`.

Can't see `myCards` member declaration, but I think it is declared like `Cards myCards`, where `Cards` is a class, which constructor accepts size of the cards deck.